STM32 pushbutton interrupt
So here's the code for my pushbutton
void PB_Init(void){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
    GPIOC->MODER |= ( 0x0 << GPIO_MODER_MODE13_Pos);
    GPIOC->PUPDR |= ( 0x1 << GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13_Pos);
}

void EXTI15_10_Init(void){
    PB_Init(); // Initialize PC13 as input.

    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<14);      // Enable System configuration controller
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<7); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<6); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] |= (1<<5);  // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<4); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
    EXTI->IMR |= (1<<13);         // Disable interrupt request mask on EXTI line 13
    EXTI->FTSR |= (1<<13);        // Enable EXTI on Falling edge
    EXTI->RTSR &= ~(1<<13);       // Disable EXTI on Rising edge
    RCC->APB2ENR &= ~(1<<14);     // Disable System configuration controller
}
volatile bool flag=0;
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
    if(flag==0){
    TIM2->CR1|=TIM_CR1_CEN;
    flag=!flag;
    EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

    }else{
        TIM2->CR1&=~TIM_CR1_CEN;
        flag=!flag;
        EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt
    }

}


void Interrupt_Init(void){
    EXTI15_10_Init(); // Step 1, this is defined elsewhere
    NVIC->IP[EXTI15_10_IRQn] =  (1 << 4);    // Step 3: Set priority to 1
    NVIC->ISER[40 >> 5] |= (1 << (40 % 32)); // Step 4: Enable interrupt
}


The issue with it is that whenever I push the button, my timer doesnt pause, it behaves randomly, goes to maximum-minimum, you never know. Never truly pauses
Tried messing with the flags and such, but to no avail

You may have other problems, but GPIOC->MODER |= ( 0x0 << GPIO_MODER_MODE13_Pos); doesn't do anything.

Why are you disabling APB2? This seems... unwise.

Do you physically debounce the button? Have you checked using breakpoints the code takes the expected path in the interrupt handler? Does it even enter it?

Oh I havent used breakpoints... not really good at debugging, will investigate that later

my timer doesnt pause, it behaves randomly, goes to maximum-minimum what does this exactly mean, how do you observe that?  Never truly pauses  What do you mean by "truly pauses"?

@wek when I say pause, it means it should go 1 2 3 4 PAUSE ! 4 4 4 4, not like, 1 2 3 4 PAUSE max max max, it resets to maximum or minimum value at random and Im not sure what's the root cause for that, gonna review it with my mentor

@PetarRistic, are you talking about TIM2_CNT? Stackoverflow does not support discussion; post complete compilable code exhibiting the problem in your thread at the STM32 forum, after that we can discuss it further there.

Here's the final piece of code that did the trick, there are a couple of key things I must say before you go through this code. All of the computation was REMOVED from the IRQ handler because my mentor told me it's bad practice to do ANY logic in the IRQ, so it has been moved to main as in the answer i will post about on my other question about a push button. I think that is it.
void PB_Init(void){
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
GPIOC->MODER |= ( 0x0 << GPIO_MODER_MODE13_Pos);
GPIOC->PUPDR |= ( 0x1 << GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13_Pos);}

void EXTI15_10_Init(void){
PB_Init(); // Initialize PC13 as input.

RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<14);      // Enable System configuration controller
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<7); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<6); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] |= (1<<5);  // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(1<<4); // Select Port C as source, EXTIx = 0b0010
EXTI->IMR |= (1<<13);         // Disable interrupt request mask on EXTI 
EXTI->FTSR |= (1<<13);        // Enable EXTI on Falling edge
EXTI->RTSR &= ~(1<<13);       // Disable EXTI on Rising edge
}


void Interrupt_Init(void){
EXTI15_10_Init(); 
NVIC->IP[EXTI15_10_IRQn] =  (1 << 4);    
NVIC->ISER[40 >> 5] |= (1 << (40 % 32)); 
}

union InterruptFlag {
struct {
   volatile bool flag: 1; // Just one bit for our flag
   volatile bool press: 1;
} bits_access;
uint32_t reg; // We'll use this for byte access
};
volatile union InterruptFlag flag = { .bits_access.flag = 0 }; // 
Initialize to 0
volatile uint16_t pressTime;
volatile bool lastButtonPress=0;
volatile bool buttonPress=1;

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
flag.bits_access.flag = !flag.bits_access.flag;
EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

}

void clearIR(void){
flag.bits_access.flag = 0;
buttonPress=0;

}

